# post data instead of using httpwebrequest, post-aync or web client

Tags: c#, file, http, model-view-controller

Is there any other way to post data instead of using  httpwebrequest, post-aync or web client in c#. I'm trying to implement a system that will support sending 15MB files from the client to server-side.

Can someone please give me an idea how to solve this... thanks!

this is how my server-side looks like...

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\in\1.txt";
string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
Uri uri = new Uri(filePath);
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);


string postUrl = "http://localhost:1234/api/value/Files";
string contentType = "application/soap+xml";

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

// Set up the request properties.
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = contentType;
//request.UserAgent = userAgent;
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
//request.ContentLength = content.Length;


//soap message format
String soapMessage = soapMessage =
        @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://dasasd/soap/envelope/' 
        xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
        <soap:Body>
        <worl xmlns='http://tempuri.org/' />
            <name>{0}</name>            
            <Content>";

//Sending message
string message = string.Format(soapMessage,
            name, contentType ?? "application/octet-stream",
            content);

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{                
    requestStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(content), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(content));
     requestStream.Close();
}

return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Comment: Why not use some sort of (already available) file upload controls?

Comment: i have to use http... i'm not suppose to use other protocols..

Comment: I suggested a control not different protocol!!!

Comment: Can you give me an example

Comment: Since you're not up to use another protocol, why you can't rely on HttpWebRequest or similar? Does your IIS server have an upload limit? If so: http://ajaxuploader.com/large-file-upload-iis-asp-net.htm

Comment: I'm trying to host it in my console application...i'm not really sure how to increase the maxAllowedContentLength in it? i'm not using IIS...

Comment: Are you building the client (stand-alone, desktop application) or the server part? You need to add ALL those details in your question, and state why the vanilla options doesn't work in your scenario.

Comment: My client-side and server-side are 2 console applications... i'm sorry i'm new to stack overflow... the issue is i'm not able to send the big size files... i  will post my server side code in the question... just give me a sec...

Comment: i'm trying to send the response as soap message... this works, but i try to increase the file size, it's giving an error saying... size is too long